# Open source tool to do OCR

Tags: open-source, java, ocr, text-processing

I would like to parse the text content (OCR) from these image file types and index them and make them available for my lucene search engine for search.

> .ai .bmp .gif .jpeg .jpg .png .psd .ttf

Can someone suggest me some open source tools available to do OCR from image files? And comparison on the available tools?

Comment: Tesseract is generally recognized as the most accurate free software for OCR. Image file format shouldn't be an issue because you can always use a different program, like ImageMagick, to convert to PNG. For us to give any more specific recommendation than that, you would need to explain what feature or features you need that not every OCR program would have.

Comment: I just need to extract the text content within the image (which can be of above formats) @Kodiologist